# Automatically change y-axis ranges

Tags: excel, vba

I'm currently using the following code to automatically update the y-axis min and max for charts in excel:

```
Sub AdjustVerticalAxis()
'PURPOSE: Adjust Y-Axis according to Min/Max of Chart Data

Dim cht As ChartObject
Dim srs As Series
Dim FirstTime  As Boolean
Dim MaxNumber As Double
Dim MinNumber As Double
Dim MaxChartNumber As Double
Dim MinChartNumber As Double
Dim Padding As Double

'Input Padding on Top of Min/Max Numbers (Percentage)
  Padding = 0.1  'Number between 0-1

'Optimize Code
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Loop Through Each Chart On ActiveSheet
  For Each cht In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects

'First Time Looking at This Chart?
  FirstTime = True

'Determine Chart's Overall Max/Min From Connected Data Source
  For Each srs In cht.Chart.SeriesCollection
    'Determine Maximum value in Series
      MaxNumber = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(srs.Values)

    'Store value if currently the overall Maximum Value
      If FirstTime = True Then
        MaxChartNumber = MaxNumber
      ElseIf MaxNumber > MaxChartNumber Then
        MaxChartNumber = MaxNumber
      End If

    'Determine Minimum value in Series (exclude zeroes)
      MinNumber = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(srs.Values)

    'Store value if currently the overall Minimum Value
      If FirstTime = True Then
        MinChartNumber = MinNumber
      ElseIf MinNumber < MinChartNumber Or MinChartNumber = 0 Then
        MinChartNumber = MinNumber
      End If

    'First Time Looking at This Chart?
      FirstTime = False
  Next srs

'Rescale Y-Axis
  cht.Chart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = MinChartNumber * (1 - Padding)
  cht.Chart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = MaxChartNumber * (1 + Padding)

  Next cht

'Optimize Code
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

The code works fine, I would jut like to make the following adjustments:

1. I'd like the code to only run on the chart/(s) I have selected (i.e. not all them at once)
2. The y-axis minimum and maximum that are outputted by the code are rounded to the nearest 10,100,1000,etc. (i.e. the equivalent of the =ROUND(A1,-1) function in excel) so as to avoid an axis that goes from 4247 to 6747 (I like it to be 4250 to 6750)

Thomas

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53617418/edit) to let us know what the question actually is. I assume you want: 1) the code to work on something other than the selected chart -- but what? and 2) you don't want rounding or you want the values rounded to something else -- but what?

Comment: Edited, hopefully that makes more sense but let me know if not

Comment: For looping through selected charts, see [this](https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/the-code-vault/vba-code-loop-selected-excel-charts)

Answer (score 0):

For the min/max values you can use:

```
'Determine Maximum value in Series
MaxNumber = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(srs.Values)
MaxNumber  = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundUp(MaxNumber, -1)
```

Similarly:

```
'Determine Minimum value in Series (exclude zeroes)
MinNumber = Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(srs.Values)
MinNumber  = Application.WorksheetFunction.RoundDown(MinNumber, -1)
```

The idea is that after you've determine the min and max values, you round them using the `ROUNDUP` and `ROUNDDOWN` worksheet functions

Comment: Hi cybernetic, unfortunately I can't seem to get this to work, where in the code was this meant to go?